# PHP email form WITH ATTACHMENT (with or without PHPmailer)

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer

I am using the below PHP code that takes values from an HTML form and sends an email in HTML. This works fine for me.

Now I need to add an ATTACHMENT field that will send the attachment along with the email (with or without storing the file on the server). Can someone please suggest how to do it with or without PHPmailer?

Thanks!

```
<?php

if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['address'])) {
    die('Error: Missing variables');
}

$name=$_POST['name'];
$mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
$position=$_POST['position'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$message=$_POST['message'];

$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$to="email@server.com";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";  
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";  
$headers = 'From: '.$_POST['name'].' <'.$_POST['email'].'>';

    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$subject='Job Application from '.$name."\n\n\n";
$body.='Name: <b>'.$name."</b><br>\n";
$body.='Mobile No: <b>'.$mobile."</b><br>\n";
$body.='Position: <b>'.$position."</b><br>\n";
$body.='Email: <b>'.$email."</b><br>\n";
$body.='Message: <b>'.$message."</b><br>\n";

$body.='IP address of the submitter: '."\n".$ip."\n";

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$email."\r\n";

if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    header("Location: thank-you.html"); 
} else {
    echo "Something has gone wrong! Please try again!"; 
}

?>
```

Comment: This code is buggy and vulnerable to attack. You should start with [this example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps) that is supplied with PHPMailer, which does exactly what you ask.

Comment: Thanks Synchro, I tried it but didn't work. It said – Mailer Error: Could not instantiate mail function. Any idea?

Comment: Read [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). It means you have no local mail server or your PHP is misconfigured. You could switch to SMTP, see the other examples.

Comment: Thanks Synchro... But I've given up phpmailer, it's too damn complicated just for a small function of attaching a goddamn file. Isn't their an east way to upload and email attachment?

Comment: That is really minimal, trivial code, that is also clear, safe and tested, but with an attitude like that you're unlikely to get much help or sympathy.

Comment: Sorry man... But I really tried whatever I could understand... The main difficulty to me is how to pass <input name=""> values to the PHPmailer. And I don't understand how the user uploaded files get passed on to $mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

Also, I keep getting "No class SMTP in class.phpmailer.php."

I don't like to give up easily but I wasted an entire day yesterday and today not being able to find a reliable solution to something that was easily handled in the previous version of PHP.

:-(

Comment: You're not using the example code I pointed at, which makes use of the autoloader to find the SMTP class. The example shows you exactly how it gets the uploaded file into PHPMailer - that only involves 3 lines of code (10, 11 and 22), really not hard! The way uploads are handled in PHP and PHPMailer has not changed in years.

Comment: Really appreciate it man... I tried it but it didn't work for me... But I'll keep your word and try it again... Can I bother you again if I get stuck?

Comment: Sure, but you've got to be more precise than "it didn't work" if you're going to get help from anyone. I'm not interested in modifying your original code as it's not worth keeping and it's far harder than using PHPMailer.

Comment: Sure I understand mate... I'll give you the exact errors, if any.... Sorry for pestering you so much... and thanks again for being so kind ;-)

Comment: Hey Marcus... Thanks a lot mate for insisting on me to use phpmailer. It has worked! I guess it wasn't working earlier due to my server, which I upgraded to PHP 5.5 yesterday, from an older version. I guess the delayed upgrade might have been the reason as to why it didn't work earlier. Just one issue right now... I want the filename to be what the user uploads and not 'My uploaded file'. And how do I set the file types? max size error? etc.

Comment: `$mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $_FILES['userfile']['name']);`. File type is set automatically by PHPMailer. You can change max size in the form. File type is set automatically by PHPailer.

Comment: Thanks buddy! You're a rockstar! Probably my last question to you... how do you pass input values to phpmailer and to message body? I tried $name=$_POST['name']; but it didn't work. May be there's a different syntax for it? I've been Googling... Thanks!

Comment: Just append your variables to the body like `$mail->Body .= $_POST['name'];` and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! And my last question... Does phpmailer have an inbuilt captcha function?

Comment: No, that's way outside its scope.

Comment: Okay no problem mate. Do let me know if I can be of any assistance to you in future. My forte is design. Thanks for all your help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to use PHPMailer..
You can get the documentation and tutorial [here](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tutorial).
This is the code for a basic mail and attaching files:

```
<?php
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the line that attaches the file- $mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");

Comment: The file must be on your server.

Comment: Thanks Arun. But how do I get the values from <input name=""> as the form is in an HTML page.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and that link (and the code) is years out of date. PHPMailer now lives [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/).

Comment: Hey Synchro buddy... Can you please help with a more precise answer?

Answer (score -1):

```
$filePath = 'foldername/attachment.zip';

$file = fopen($filePath,'rb'); 
$data = fread($file,filesize($filePath)); 
fclose($file);
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

Content-Type: application/zip; name="attachment.zip"  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  
Content-Disposition: attachment 

$data
```

Add this code before this line "if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {".

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: should it be in this format? – $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$email."\r\n";    As otherwise it's giving me an error in Dreamweaver.

Comment: $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; $headers .= 'From: '.$email."\r\n";  this code will be mentioned and with my code will be bellow header.